# How to run complex queries in Tarantool

Tags: lua, tarantool

I've always worked with relational DBs and recently decided to migrate a performance-critial service from SQL Server to Tarantool with a hope to take advantage of the fast in-memory search and processing. I've got a couple of questions while planning for the migration.

I've got a table with about one million records containing pricing information which means I'm dealing mostly with numbers and uuids. First, I need to run a select containing multiple conditions to get a subset of the data, like

```
SELECT * FROM rates WHERE SupplierId = @SupplierId AND ProductId = @ProductId AND (LocalDistributionZoneId = @LocalDistributionZoneId OR LocalDistributionZoneId IS NULL)
```

Q1: What is the strategy of running such a query in Lua? Do I create an index for each field in the predicate or I can go along with one secondary composite index?

Q2: Will it be more covenient to run such a query in SQL (box.sql.execute) rather than in pure Lua? Will it be considerably slower than running the same query in pure Lua?

Q3: If I use SQL, is it possible to review the execusion plan to make sure that the query I run really uses the indexes I've defined in the space?

Ok, after I've get the results from the first query I need to analyse the data and then based on the results of analysis, run one more query on the dataset returned by the first query.

Q4: Can Tarantool help me in dealing with the intermediate dataset? More specifically, may I somehow run more queries against the intermediate subset of tuples leveraging the indexes created in the space? Or, I would need to implement alternative strategies like re-add the intrim results to a temporary space with pre-defined indexes and then do another select, or implement further search myself?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Don't. Use SQL, it's faster: it doesn't create garbage collected objects for intermediate execution results.
2. Yes, please use our SQL features for that.
3. Use EXPLAIN statement.
4. I don't know what you exactly mean by "help". You could try to whatever strategy works best: create a more complex query, save the original query in a view to use in the resulting query, create a temporary table and work with it. To give more details let's look if the execution plan Tarantool chooses is good enough or you have to manually optimize it.

Comment: " you have to manually optimize it" -- can you manually optimize the plan? can you add hints or something?